# Identify child records that were re-parented due to Account merge

Tags: account, merge

When an account, Account B gets merged into Account A, the child opportunities are reparented to Account A. I want to identify which opportunities belonged to Account B before the merge. I tried using the history object but it seems changes due to merge are not entered there.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you set field history tracking on the Account Name field on the Opportunity object, you should see the reparenting entry on the opp record.